# NSEvent or NSNotification when window becomes active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In Mac OS X, is there a method to override that runs every time a window gains focus?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. [NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), depending on your intent.